# Store Column Values in Array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store the title(summary) and date(created) of an event in an array. But I think im missing something in my loop.

```
<?php
$summary = array();
$date = array();

mysql_connect('mysql.server', 'myUsername', 'myPass') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mxgsite") or die(mysql_error());
$query_summary = mysql_query('SELECT summary FROM event_info') or die(mysql_error());
$query_date = mysql_query('SELECT created FROM event_details') or die(mysql_error());

$row_summary = mysql_fetch_array($query_summary);
$row_date = mysql_fetch_array($query_date);

$i = 0;
while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query_summary))) {
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query_date);
    $summary[] = $row['summary'];
    $date[] = $row['created'];
    echo $summary[$i] . " " . $date[$i] . "<br ?>";
    $i++;
}
```

I know i'm getting values because I can echo out 1 value, but if I want to put all the values in an array and try to echo out that array I keep getting blank values?

Comment: I think your bigger problem is that there's no guarantee whatsoever that row x from the `event_info` table has anything to do with row x from the `event_details` table, no?

Comment: they use event_id as it's shared key?

Comment: Agree with deceze.  If the 2 tables can be related by an "eventid" or something of that nature, you're better off doing a join and getting summary and created in 1 query.  That way, you can then store and work with them as linked pairs.

Comment: @Howdy You're not using that `event_id` anywhere in your query though, so you're just getting random rows.

Comment: :S i'm going to have to search joins then. I wanted them in 2 separate arrays though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me like you are trying to do too many things here.  Since the 2 sets of values are not being stored in a way where they are related/linked to each other, you might as well deal with them in separate while loops.  Try something like this:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_summary)){
     $summary[] = $row[0];
 }
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_date)){
     $date[] = $row[0];
 }
```

If you want to relate the tables, per the comments above, you can try something more like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT a.eventid, a.summary, b.created 
                         FROM event_info a 
                         join event_details b 
                         on a.eventid = b.eventid');

$events = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $event = array();
    foreach ($row as $key=>$value){
      $event[$key]=$value;
    }
    $events[] = $event;
}
```

Comment: +1, except for that inner loop. You're just copying an array into another array, which is unnecessary.